# add more values to a key python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

i would like to add this:

```
{
   "Category": "Fruit"
}
```

to this:

```
{
   "Category": "Vegetable"
{
```

so I can have:

```
"Name": "Menu1",
"Categories":[
    {
       "Category": "Fruit"
    {
    }
       "Category": "Vegetable"
    {
   ]
```

I'm creating a list of dicts and sometimes I can have 2 dicts with the same key["Name"] and i would like to to avoid having the two dicts with the same name separated. Currently I'm doing this to check if the "Name" already exists and if not create it and add it to the list:

```
if len(List) != 0: #checking if the list has something
   for x in List:
       if menu['Name'] == x['Name']:
          menu['Category'].append(Category) #if exist add data to the existing one
          break
       else:    
          List.append(menu) #if doesn't exist add it
          break
else:
   List.append(menu) #if is empty add an item
```

Comment: In Python empty lists are falsey you `if List:` is equivalent to `if len(List) != 0:`

Comment: `['Category']` should be `menu['Category']`

Comment: If you `break` in both `if` and `else`, you only process the first element of `List`, so there's no reason to loop.

Comment: Maybe the first `else:` should be unindented so it's on the `for` loop, not `if`.

Comment: give examples of input and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was this:

```
for item in my_list:
    if item['Name'] == menu['Name']: #Exist in list
        print('Exist')
        var = []
        var.append({'Category': Category})
        x['Categories'] += var
        cod = []
        cod.append({'Code': code})
        x['Codes'] += cod
        break
else:
    my_list.append(menu) #doesn't exist
    print('not matched')
```

Comment: How does this add another category to the Categories list?

Comment: That's the same as `x['Categories'].append({'Category': Category})`. There's no need to create another list.

Comment: In my answer I assumed that `Category` was a dictionary like `{'Category': "Fruit"}`, not a string.

Comment: it wasn't working for me:( when i was using `.append(something)` that `something` was overwriting the previous value

Answer (score 1):

You should be appending to `x['Category']`, not an unnamed list that contains the string `'Category'`.

The `else:` block that adds the name should be on the `for` loop. This will execute if the loop ends normally instead of from `break`, which means the name wasn't found.

There's no need to check the length of `List` first. If it's empty, the loop will end normally and the `else:` block will execute.

```
for x in List:
    if menu['Name'] == x['Name']:
        x['Category'].append(Category) #if exist add data to the existing one
        break
else:    
    List.append(menu) #if doesn't exist add it
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! it helped me a lot resolving the problem but i had to change it a bit